# Implementing ER Diagram in MySQL, receiving Error 1064 during altering

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to establish an ER diagram for my database. There are 5 tables in my database.

[image]

When I want to make the relationship between industry_number and company_inustry, it always said there is a 1064 error.
my code is:

```
ALTER TABLE company_inustry
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Detailed Industry)
REFERENCES Industry_number(Detailed Industry)
```

> Error is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Industry)
> REFERENCES Industry_number(Detailed Industry)' at line 2.

I'm a new learner. Please help me... Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You have spaced in the column names so you need quote them.
It would be a better idea to use an underscore `Detailed_Industry` as you have done in the table names. If you do not you will have the same problem in every query that refers to these columns.

```
ALTER TABLE company_inustry ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Detailed Industry") REFERENCES Industry_number("Detailed Industry")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use double quotes (" ") if you have space in name of the tables. use underscore as a good industry practice.

Use this query for correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE company_inustry ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Detailed Industry") REFERENCES Industry_number("Detailed Industry")
```